# Weirdness when "flattening" a column in a data frame (pandas in Python) -- source dictionary's keys also change?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm encountering some strange behavior when I attempt to "flatten" a column in a dataFrame.  By flatten, I'm referring to when the values in the column are dictionaries, and it would be more desirable for those dictionaries to be their own columns in the dataFrame.

So, for example:

```
test_dict = {'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1,2,3], 'blah':[{'foo':'Wilma'},{'bar':'Betty'},{'fizz':'Jane'}]}

test_df = pd.DataFrame (test_dict)
test_df.head()
```

Which displays:

```
    foo bar            blah
0   a   1   {'foo': 'Wilma'}
1   b   2   {'bar': 'Betty'}
2   c   3   {'fizz': 'Jane'}
```

Now I want to flatten the "blah" column.  But some of the keys in the dictionaries in that column are the same as the existing columns of `test_df`, so I'm going to add a prefix to them while I pull them out to make them unique:

```
list_of_rows = []

for index, row in test_df.iterrows():
    rowDict = row.to_dict()
    blah = rowDict.pop('blah')
    for key in list (blah):
        newkey = 'blah_' + key
        blah[newkey] = blah.pop(key)
    rowDict.update(blah)
    list_of_rows.append(rowDict)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)
```

(I'm sure there are many more efficient ways of doing this)

Now, let's take a look at df2:

```
df2.head()

    foo bar blah_foo    blah_bar    blah_fizz
0   a   1   Wilma           NaN          NaN
1   b   2   NaN           Betty          NaN
2   c   3   NaN             NaN         Jane
```

This looks the way I'd expect.

But now let's take a look at `test_dict` (the dictionary this dataFrame was originally created from):

```
test_dict

{'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 'bar': [1, 2, 3],
 'blah': [{'blah_foo': 'Wilma'}, {'blah_bar': 'Betty'}, {'blah_fizz': 'Jane'}]}
```

Somehow, the original dictionary's keys were all changed as well.

I'm sure there's a simple explanation for this, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what's happening here.

Comment: Can you try `import copy; test_df = pd.DataFrame(copy.deepcopy(test_dict))` and see if it is still doing same thing? I don't have a chance to try it but I think pandas creates a shallow copy of your original dictionary so it also changes when you are manipulating your dataframe.

Comment: Make a deep copy on the test dict to prevent mutable changes. As recommended by @Asocia

Comment: Yep, this is the bit I wasn't getting -- that pandas makes a shallow copy of the dictionary.  Doing a deepcopy does keep the original dictionary intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack dictionaries from a column using `pd.to_series` as such:

```
df.merge(
    df['blah'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("foo_"),
    how='outer',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True
    )

    foo bar blah    foo_foo foo_bar foo_fizz
0   a   1   {'foo': 'Wilma'}    Wilma   NaN NaN
1   b   2   {'bar': 'Betty'}    NaN Betty   NaN
2   c   3   {'fizz': 'Jane'}    NaN NaN Jane
```

Alternatively, if your data is sourced from a json, you can use [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) which operates as follows:

```
test_records = [
    {"foo":"a","bar":1, "blah":{"foo":"Wilma"}},
    {"foo":"b","bar":2, "blah":{"bar":"Betty"}},
    {"foo":"c","bar":3, "blah":{"fizz":"Jane"}}
    ]

pd.json_normalize(test_records)

    foo bar blah.foo    blah.bar    blah.fizz
0   a   1   Wilma   NaN NaN
1   b   2   NaN Betty   NaN
2   c   3   NaN NaN Jane
```

Comment: While not exactly what I asked, the tip about `json_normalize` is very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome @DavidGoldman -- as per your Q, does the 1st 1/2 of my response provide an answer?